# Finding the cost-minimising production allocation in a Cournot merger with symmetric costs

Tags: microeconomics

Suppose I have 3 firms in a market. They have an identical, convex cost function, $C(q) = 20q + q^2$ = $C_1 = C_2 = C_3$, and each firm produces in their own factory.

Market demand is linear, $P=200-Q$ , where $Q = q_1 + q_2 + q_3$

Now, suppose that Firm 2 and Firm 3 merge, but costs don't change. The new Firm (call it Firm $M$), has the same cost function as above.

How would Firm $M$ decide whether to produce at 1 factory entirely and close the inactive one down, or split production between two factories? **Specifically, which choice would lead to lower costs?**

Intuitively, since the cost function is convex,  it would be beneficial to split production between two factories. I don't know how to identify Firm M's cost function when it produces in both factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to model the decision problem of firm $M$. In case they produce a total quantity of $q_M$, they can split this between factories $1$ and $2$. Firm $M$ can minimize the cost of producing $q_M$ units by solving the problem
$$
\min_{q_1,q_2} C_1(q_1) + C_2(q_2) = \min_{q_1,q_2} 20q_1 + q_1^2 + 20q_2 + q_2^2
$$
subject to the constraint
$$
q_M = q_1 + q_2.
$$
(And the usual non-negativity constraints, but those will not matter here.)

The solution to the above problem yields $C_M(q_M)$. If the solution is such that $q_1,q_2$ are both positive, then no factory should be shuttered.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I get $ C_m(q_m) = 20q_m + (1/2)q_m^2$, which yields a lower cost than when producing at only 1 factory . I suppose it makes sense - since $20q_m$ is linear so the difference between producing at one factory only and two factories will simply be in how the production is allocated across the polynomial term i.e if $q=10$, $5^2 + 5^2 = 50 = (1/2) 10^2$